# regular expression validator in asp.net

Tags: regex

what is the regular expression to validate a text box to allow "united states social security number" and also the text "-  -" using regular expression validator.

Comment: Googling for "united states social security number regex" returns a lot of matches...

Comment: Also i need the text box to validate default  "- -" text also.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.net's Regular Expression Validator control has U.S. Social Security number as a selectable option.

Comment: Also i need the text box to validate default "- -" text also

Comment: that says a lot about the US-centric nature of ASP. I bet it doesn't have the equivalent for many other countries.

Answer (score 0):

(update: after googling, it seems that there are some requirements such as: first three digits must be 001 – 772.  So I suggest you use the info on Google since it already presents a full tutorial on how it is done.  The info below is just for a generic form).

not sure if asp.net uses a different regex syntax, but a general regex of SSN is

```
/^\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}$/
```

you may need to change it for asp.net.

the `^` is for beginning of string, `$` is for the end, and `\d` is for a single digit.  The `{3}` means it needs to repeat 3 times.

Comment: Right for number, but doesn't match `- -`

Comment: People don’t always include the `-`’s, and even when they do, they occasionally place them differently; for example, `NNN-NNN-NNN`.

Comment: if you want the "-" I would suggest having three fields on the page for the three three-digit parts, and putting a - between them. That way, the user can't do something with - that you're not expecting

Comment: Also i need the text box to validate default "- -" text also.

Answer (score 0):

RegexBuddy suggests

```
\b(?!000)(?!666)(?:[0-6]\d{2}|7(?:[0-356]\d|7[012]))[- ](?!00)\d{2}[- ](?!0000)\d{4}\b
```

for a US social security number. Combining this with `- -` into a .NET-friendly string gives you:

```
@"^(?:- -|(?!000)(?!666)(?:[0-6]\d{2}|7(?:[0-356]\d|7[012]))[- ](?!00)\d{2}[- ](?!0000)\d{4})$"
```

Do you also want to allow for variations in the `- -` string? For example, more spaces?